# Having trouble with my Draw function for tictactoe

Tags: javascript, arrays, tic-tac-toe

ive been learning javascript for several months and i started creating small projects to the best of my ability , i still struggle a lot but i feel like im improving. I'm creating a tictactoe game this is a revised version of my first attempt, its bad code but its an improvement from 1st attempt.  Im having trouble with the draw function , when i fill the board it logs 'tie' but the problem is if 'X' or 'O' wins with the last move itll win but still log tie. Any help is appreciated.

after couple hours i figured out how to fill the board and get a draw now im just trying to figure out how to get the win without tying when board is filled.

```js
const clear = document.getElementById("clear");
const message = document.querySelector('h2');
const allDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#board div');
const squares = Array.from(allDiv);
let player = 'O'

function board (){
    
    squares.forEach(function(e, i){
        
        squares[i].onclick = ()=>{
            squares[i].textContent = player = player === 'O' ? 'X' : 'O';
            squares[i].textContent === 'X' ? message.textContent = "It's O's turn" :
                message.textContent = "It's X's turn";
            checkWin();
            draw();
        }
    });
    
        
}
board();
const allEqual = arr => arr.every( v => v === arr[0] )

function checkWin(){

  squares[0].textContent == 'X' && squares[1].textContent == 'X' && squares[2].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[0].textContent == 'O' && squares[1].textContent == 'O' && squares[2].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[3].textContent == 'X' && squares[4].textContent == 'X' && squares[5].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[3].textContent == 'O' && squares[4].textContent == 'O' && squares[5].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[6].textContent == 'X' && squares[7].textContent == 'X' && squares[8].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[6].textContent == 'O' && squares[7].textContent == 'O' && squares[8].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[0].textContent == 'X' && squares[3].textContent == 'X' && squares[6].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[0].textContent == 'O' && squares[3].textContent == 'O' && squares[6].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[1].textContent == 'X' && squares[4].textContent == 'X' && squares[7].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[1].textContent == 'O' && squares[4].textContent == 'O' && squares[7].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[2].textContent == 'X' && squares[5].textContent == 'X' && squares[8].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[2].textContent == 'O' && squares[5].textContent == 'O' && squares[8].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[1].textContent == 'X' && squares[4].textContent == 'X' && squares[8].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[1].textContent == 'O' && squares[4].textContent == 'O' && squares[8].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
  squares[2].textContent == 'X' && squares[4].textContent == 'X' && squares[6].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : null;
  squares[2].textContent == 'O' && squares[4].textContent == 'O' && squares[6].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : null;
}
checkWin()

clear.onclick = ()=>{
    squares.forEach(function(e,i){
        squares[i].textContent = '';
        squares[i].style.color = '';
    })
};

function draw(){
    
    squares[0].textContent !== '' && squares[1].textContent !== '' &&
    squares[2].textContent !== '' && squares[3].textContent !== '' &&
    squares[4].textContent !== '' && squares[5].textContent !== '' &&
    squares[6].textContent !== '' && squares[7].textContent !== '' &&
    squares[8].textContent !== '' ? console.log('tie') : null
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(-20deg, #00cdac 0%, #8ddad5 100%);
    
}
header{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00b4db, #0083b0);
}
header h1{
    padding-top: 2%;
    color: aqua;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 0 greenyellow;
}
.container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #7cc5d5;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
.group{
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    
}
.square{
    width: 40%;
    height: 20vh;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.square-3{
    width: 40%;
    height: 20vh;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.square-a{
    width: 40%;
    height: 20vh;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.square-b{
    width: 40%;
    height: 20vh;
}
.new{
    width: 40%;
    height: 20vh;
    background: rgb(166, 165, 165);
}
div{
    font-size: 7rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Tik Tac Toe</h1>
        <h2>It's X's turn!</h2>
        <button id="p-one">X</button>
        <button id="p-two">O</button>
        <button id="clear">Play Again</button>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
        <section id="board">
       <section class="group">
            <div id="one" class="square"></div>
            <div id="two" class="square"></div>
            <div id="three" class="square-3"></div>
       </section>
       <section class="group">
        <div id="four" class="square"></div>
        <div id="five" class="square"></div>
        <div id="six" class="square-3"></div>
   </section>
   <section class="group">
        <div id="seven" class="square-a"></div>
        <div id="eight" class="square-a"></div>
        <div id="nine" class="square-b"></div>
</section>
</section>
    </section>
    <script src="toe.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="prac.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

Comment: Please post your code in here, create a working snippet where we can see the problem, not much we can dot if we can't see the code, even the link you provided is non-functional

Comment: Take the time to learn how to debug in your browser. Make each program project an opportunity to learn a little something about that. Without this skill every little program bug in every program you ever write will seem bigger and more mysterious than it really is - like your current issue I expect.  Ongoing frustration will hinder advancing your programming skills.

Comment: Post the relevant code, that's important for good analysis and answers. Links to codepen, JSfiddle, etc. is a good thing but as you change code that can invalidate answers and comments. It gets confusing for everyone. Copy relevant code into this thread and do not change that.

Comment: sorry new to stackover flow, felt like it was to much code to post so i linked the codepen

Comment: The code seems to work. now.. can you explain when it does not?! (PS: the code is really hard to debug and I believe even write or fix. Programming is not about repeating code (like you did with the many `if`s) but to find a simple algorithm, logic that can achieve the same result in a couple of readable and easily debug-gable lines)

Answer (score 0):

You could have your function `checkwin()` return the winner, or blank, instead of printing output, and have your function `draw()` return a boolean.  Then, in your main loop, you could do something like:

```
let winner=checkwin();
if (winner) {
    message.textContent=winner;
} else if draw() {
    message.textContext='Draw';
    console.log('Tie Game');
}
```

Comment: In general, your programs will be easier to maintain if you separate your logic from your presentation.  Use your functions to answer questions, and then you can reuse those same functions whether your writing to a file, crafting HTML, sending output to an API, or whatever.

Comment: thank you, i really appreciate you taking your time out of your day to help me out and thanks to everyone else. when i switched my draw() function to a boolean it wasn't returning true but when i switched it to an if statement it worked? same for my checkWin() function. why is that?

Comment: why wasn't the ternary version of my code not returning true but the if statement did? sorry for all the questions lol

Comment: @Gzus24 You are asking questions about code we can't see.  Do your refactored functions contain a `return` statement?

Answer (score 0):

> if 'X' or 'O' wins with the last move itll win but still log tie

When `checkWin()` finds a winner the rest of the function still runs and a subsequent line will over-write with `null`.

Fix like this:

Initialize the return variable with the default - null (or 'tie', etc.). **In the `false` clause use the variable not a literal `null`.** Change the variable only upon a win. If no one wins that initial value is returned.

```
function checkWin(){
  message.textContent = null;

  squares[0].textContent == 'X' && squares[1].textContent == 'X' && squares[2].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : message.textContent;
  squares[0].textContent == 'O' && squares[1].textContent == 'O' && squares[2].textContent == 'O' ? message.textContent = 'O Wins' : message.textContent;
  squares[3].textContent == 'X' && squares[4].textContent == 'X' && squares[5].textContent == 'X' ? message.textContent = 'X Wins' : message.textContent;

  // and so on

} // checkWin
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback, i changed the checkWin() function to return player and the draw() function to a boolean. sorry id put the code i changed here but im new to stack overflow